# Postion one particular image in a group of single image in css

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem in css alignment.

The problem is, i have a single image which is like collage with multiple images in it.

I want to postion on particular image in that collage using css.

I need to set that in my div background.

I checked in internet, i am unable to find a proper solution.

Thanks,
Karthikeyan J

Comment: Where is the fiddle ?

Comment: Post some code you've tried.

Comment: You might wish to review the [ask] section of Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

If you download a chrome addon called "SelectorGadget" you may be able to get the exact CSS selector for what you are trying to edit. Then just apply styling to this element. If you post your code, might be able to help more though.